# Google Cloud Datastore batch operation sequence

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I'm wondering if batched get request to datastore will preserve records order when request finished?

I'm using standard google-cloud/datastore client library to perform batched get request, like this (from Datastore's docs).

```
const keys = [taskKey1, taskKey2];

datastore.get(keys)
  .then((results) => {
    // Tasks retrieved successfully.
    const tasks = results[0];

    console.log(tasks);
  });
```

I suspected that results will be in the same order as in a keys array, but on my working example it is not.

So, am I doing something wrong, or is it Google Datastore doesn't preserves order in batch operations?

Answer (score 2):

To get ordered results, you need to use a query. First, filter by `key` values, then order by the property(ies) you want.

**See these docs for more info:**

[How to filter by `Key`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/queries#key_filters)

[How to order results](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/queries#sort_orders)

Comment: Actually that is not what I'm searching for. I need to get exactly this entities using this keys. Btw, what about performances of direct keys fetching and query fetching ways?

Comment: As I understand, by default, Datastore sorts entities by key value. Unless you use a query to determine a different sorting, it should retrieve the matching entities ordered by key. It looks like you'll need to sort the results in your application, after retrieving it (assuming you can't translate your original sorting in a Datastore command). Regarding performance, the `get()` method should be faster than a query with `key` filter, but I wouldn't expect a considerable difference unless you are performing hundreds of thousands or millions of requests daily.

Comment: That is how it is implemented currently. Manuak sorting in me code. But I really don't like this solution. Si, for now I will leave it like that, maybe Datastore developers will introduce something that solves this porblem in the future.

Comment: I understand as I wouldn't like such solution either. You can post a feature request in their [Report Bugs and Request Features page](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) (look up for "Create new Cloud Datastore issue").

Comment: I've created a several features request. Thank you.